# Can't access the website which is on and working with only one device (PC)

Tags: url, dns, ip-address

Around 2 weeks ago I suddenly became unable to use my university's classroom website from my PC. My PC is the only device having problem, I can freely access it from my phone or laptop. Website url is, classroom.btu.edu.ge. When I try to ping it form my PC it shows IP 188.93.95.169 but from Laptop it shows 104.26.12.198 which is correct one (cause I can access it from laptop). Some time ago I think i edited some dns settings from cmd or something like that, I was having problem and that solved it and I don't know how to reverse/check it if its causing the problem.

Whenever I try to to go to the url it just does nothing in the browser (tried all of them similar result)

(I don't know if I should be asking this question here so if something tell me where to move it)

Comment: This really isn't the correct site to ask this question.  But, have you tried setting your IP address including DNS to obtain automatically/dynamically?  It looks like you have your IP address set incorrectly.

Comment: honestly i dont know what have i done before i just followed some simple instruction. how can i check it.

Comment: Read https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-tcp-ip-settings-bd0a07af-15f5-cd6a-363f-ca2b6f391ace and choose the automatic for both your IP address and DNS.

Comment: Questions here are required to be about a [website you operate or manage](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). There really isn't a Stack Exchange site for troubleshooting individual computers - [Super User](http://superuser.com/) is the closest to that, so you might search there. As Trebor commented, you can can revert your DNS settings to "automatic" for the IP and DNS - or use a current version of Firefox, which now uses [DNS over HTTPS](https://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2020/02/25/firefox-continues-push-to-bring-dns-over-https-by-default-for-us-users/) and bypasses your DNS.